# Unable to open Chrome in two different user session in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have Chrome opened in Windows Server 2008 R2 server. My coworker is trying to open Chrome in a different session, but is unable to do so.

I close Chrome in my session, he is now able to open Chrome in his session.

Both of us have admin credentials to the server.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you both logged in with the same username (ie admin)?  If so, then you are out of luck.  Two sessions as the same user simply cannot run Chrome at the same time.  Chrome (and Firefox) are simply not designed to permit more then one session to be using the same browser profile.  Among other things both browsers heavily depend on the SQLite library which doesn't permit write access from more then one process.

Your choices are:

- Make sure every user has a unique username and profile
- Have everyone run [Portable Chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) from a personal folder.

Comment: Yes, we use the same username. I am out of luck then. Good to know this, thanks!